# Sending data with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

Is it possible to have if-else statements within a Guzzle query? E.g.:

```
$client       = new Client();
$resp = $client->request('POST', $url, [
'form_params' => [
'foo' => 'bar',
'foo2' => 'bar2',
if ($_POST['fusroda'] == "rawww"){
'foo3' => 'bar3',
} else { 
//don't sent rent 
}
...
]
]);
```

Apparently this isn't possible. What other options do I have?

ED: I have considered doing a if-else statement where I put a whole query in each of them, but then my code will be 1000 of lines and unstructured.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to separate logic responsible for preparing data to separate function, to keep each part of application with single responsibility only.

It could be something like that:

```
function prepareParams($params)
{
    if ($params['fusroda'] == "rawww"){
        $params['foo3'] = 'bar3';
    }
    unset($params['fusroda'];

    ...    

    return $params; 
}

$resp = $client->request('POST', $url, [
'form_params' => $this->prepareParams($paramsBeforeEdit)
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @acabala. It's a really good suggestion, but I doesn't quite fit my needs. 

As I mentioned I have a scenario where there are many variables to take into considerations. So if I need to have if-else statements within the prepareParams - I need to have a lot... Then I need to have between 10-15 if-else statements. 

Isn't there any easier and more structured way to do this?

Comment: And I don't quite understand your function. What is the variable $paramsBeforeEdit? Where does it come from?

Comment: `$paramsBeforeEdit` are all parameters you want to set as form_params, so an array: 
'foo' => 'bar',
'foo2' => 'bar2',
['fusroda'] =>"rawww"

You already have it somewere.

Comment: Can you please give a more comprehensive example then?